# Reshape dataframe into a timeseries when time information is split into columns and index?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, pivot-table

The dataframe below tracks daily changes in parameters `"rate"`, `"pressure"`, and `"cut"`. The date information is split between a *column* `'Months&year'` (Jan 2024, Dec 2023, etc...) on one side, while days (1-31) make the *index* of the dataframe:

```py
dataframe.head()

Month&Year  parameter   1   2   3   ..  31
Jan 2024    rate       22   1   7       6
Jan 2024    pressure    67  8   8       8
Jan 2024    cut         2   67  7       2
Dec 2023    rate        8   9   1       0
Dec 2023    pressure    6   8   11      3
Dec 2023    cut         7   8   77      8
```

I seek to gather the date information (`"day"`, `"month&year"`) on one side so as to reshape the dataframe into a timeseries, this way:

```py
Month&Year  parameter   rate    pressure    cut
Jan 2024    1   22  67  2
Jan 2024    2   1   8   67
Jan 2024    3   7   8   7
..          
Jan 2024    31  6   8   2
    
Dec 2023    1   8   6   7
Dec 2023    2   9   8   8
Dec 2023    3   1   11  77
..          
Dec 2023    31  0   3   8
```

I guess I will need to split this dataframe to multiple datafames using groupby for month&year, transpose each of new datasets, and then merge them again.

Here is what I have achieved so far, when I used groupby and splited this dataframe to separate dataframes:

```py
in:
    mo=dataframe.groupby('Month&year')
    dataframe_months=[mo.get_group(x) for x in mo.groups]
    print ("result: \"n", dataframe_months)


out:

    Month&Year  parameter   1   2   3   ..  31
    Jan 2024    rate    22  1   7       6
    Jan 2024    pressure    67  8   8       8
    Jan 2024    cut 2   67  7       2
                                                
                        
    Month&Year  parameter   1   2   3   ..  31
    Dec 2023    rate    8   9   1       0
    Dec 2023    pressure    6   8   11      3
    Dec 2023    cut 7   8   77      8
```

Could you please suggest how can I refer to splited dataframes without writing manually their names (there are many years) to transpose them and merge in the same order as before.

Comment: the pd.concat function might work well if it addresses your issue and the order's fine. So pd.concat(dataframe_months)

Comment: @OCa thank you very much! your solution is interesting, I will try it too. Sorry I haven't login for a long time, since I solved it via  via groupby, transpose and concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed strategy looks unnecessarily complicated for what is a mere **reshaping** of your dataframe. The [pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) recommends a **pivot_table**:

**Repeating input data for clarity**
(skipping undisclosed days)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month&Year': ['Jan 2024','Jan 2024','Jan 2024','Dec 2023','Dec 2023','Dec 2023'],
                   'parameter': ['rate', 'pressure', 'cut', 'rate', 'pressure', 'cut'],
                   1: [22, 67, 2, 8, 6, 7],
                   2: [1, 8, 67, 9, 8, 8],
                   3: [7, 8, 7, 1, 11, 77],
                   31: [6, 8, 2, 0, 3, 8]})
df

  Month&Year parameter   1   2   3  31
0   Jan 2024      rate  22   1   7   6
1   Jan 2024  pressure  67   8   8   8
2   Jan 2024       cut   2  67   7   2
3   Dec 2023      rate   8   9   1   0
4   Dec 2023  pressure   6   8  11   3
5   Dec 2023       cut   7   8  77   8
```

**1. Pivot `'Month&Year'` and the *days* (1 to 31) to the same side**
Here we swap `'Month&Year'` up as another level of columns using `pivot_table`, then transpose (`T`) and finally flatten the table (`reset_index`).

```py
dfp = pd.pivot_table(data    = df,
                     values  = [1,2,3,31],
                     columns = 'Month&Year',
                     index   = 'parameter'
                    ).T.reset_index()

parameter  level_0 Month&Year  cut  pressure  rate
0                1   Dec 2023    7         6     8
1                1   Jan 2024    2        67    22
2                2   Dec 2023    8         8     9
3                2   Jan 2024   67         8     1
4                3   Dec 2023   77        11     1
5                3   Jan 2024    7         8     7
6               31   Dec 2023    8         3     0
7               31   Jan 2024    2         8     6
```

**2. Finishing touch for readability of index and columns**

- Your desired output dataframe showed `'parameter'` as name for the column holding the days. This felt confusing so I named it `'Day'` instead.
- As a result of the pivot, the label `'parameter'` ends up as the name of the *columns* index, where it becomes confusing as well. We can simply remove that label.

```py
dfp = dfp.rename(columns = {'level_0' : 'Day'})
dfp.columns = dfp.columns.rename(None)
dfp

   Day Month&Year  cut  pressure  rate
0    1   Dec 2023    7         6     8
1    1   Jan 2024    2        67    22
2    2   Dec 2023    8         8     9
3    2   Jan 2024   67         8     1
4    3   Dec 2023   77        11     1
5    3   Jan 2024    7         8     7
6   31   Dec 2023    8         3     0
7   31   Jan 2024    2         8     6
```

Sorting by date will be another question involving pandas.datetime.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is an interesting solution, I will try it too.   Sorry I haven't login for a long time, since I solved it via my described plan.